# Where can i find pthread dll files for VC6?

Tags: php, pthreads

Can anyone tell me the path for download the Pthread files( pthreadVC6.dll, php_pthreads.dll ) .

I am using the php build extension VC6 and php version 5.3.5, i could not find the thread download location for my build version.

I tried on this URL. [Pthread](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/)

But gives me VC9 files only.

Comment: Using an ancient PHP with an even older compiler is probably not a good idea. Why don't you use at least halfway recent software that't actively maintained and supported? That said, please reread the posting guidelines, your question is factually off-topic.

Comment: I am maintaining the project which was created using phpversion 5.3.5 with VC6 only, i need to apply thread concept on this. I can not go with higher version due to most of the functions has been deprecated.